# How to redirect in Laravel form on Post request?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and have run into following issue:

I have a form that should redirect on Post request but redirect does not happen.

This is my form:

```
<form action="{{route('cart-store')}}" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$product->id}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{{$product->name}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="{{$product->price}}">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary shop-button">Add to Card</button>
</form>
```

This is CartController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    Cart::add($request->id, $request->name, 1, $request->price)->associate('App\Product');

    return redirect()->route('cart-index')->with('success_message', 'Item was added to your cart!');

}
```

And this is the route:

```
Route::post('/cart', 'CartContrloller@store')->name('cart-store');
```

When I click on submit button, the URL gets filled with product data but I reamain on the same page instead of being regirected to Cart.

I have no clue why this is happenning. Is threre a way to at least find out what is broken? I am on 5.7 version.

Comment: Do you have a cart index route?

Comment: yes, /cart route is reachable from url

Comment: the redirect function redirects if the url is a GET request, since you have a POST route, it isnt redirecting and also i can see you are redirecting to the same store function, just make sure, its not calling itself.

Comment: Route::get('/cart', 'CartContrloller@index')->name('cart-index');  exists.

Comment: btw, i can alter the form before submitting and add the item to my cart with any price i want?

Comment: Can you please try with redirect(route('cart-index'));

Comment: `'CartContrloller@store'` is the controller really named `CartContrloller`? and the URL should not be filled with data, that would imply your form is GET not POST ... are you using javascript here and not showing it?

Comment: 'CartContrloller' is the contrloller. And yes, Url, gets filled with pruduct data that is requested in the frorm, while it is Post method.

Comment: Is the product being added to cart?

Comment: How can I check this?

Answer (score 3):

I guess the best practice here could be using laravel's redirect back :

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success_message','any message you want')
```

you can not redirect to a post method, post routes except: csrf_token and some data with POST method, redirect it self is HTTP GET.

Comment: I should be redirrected to: Route::post('/cart', 'CartContrloller@store')->name('cart-store'); Not back to the same page...

Comment: @PinPiguin redirection in laravel can not be post, because laravel is ready to fetch some data out of post request. redirect uses HTTP GET method.
In that case it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller you need to use route('cart-index') in redirect()

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{

    Cart::add($request->id, $request->name, 1, $request->price)->associate('App\Product');

    return redirect(route('cart-index'))->with('success_message', 'Item was added to your cart!');

}
```

or if you need to redirect back try:

```php
return redirect()->back()->with('success_message', 'Item was added to your cart!');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write this codes in your project:

```
Route::get('/cart', 'CartContrloller@index')->name('cart-index');
Route::post('/cart', 'CartContrloller@store')->name('cart-store');

public function index()
{
    return view('card.form');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
    Cart::add($request->id, $request->name, 1, $request->price)->associate('App\Product');

    return redirect()->route('cart-index');
}
```

check this out and if you are seeding form parameters again in your url I am sure that your blade form method is not post, its get, maybe your changes doesnt saved!